# Extracting the hostname/ip address from an URL in Android

Tags: java, android, string, url, substring

Let's say I saved a URL of http://192.168.0.123:321. I just want to extract 192.168.0.123.I can do this by using this method
`url.toString().substring(7,(url.length()-4));`

But what if the saved URL is http://192.168.0.1:12 ?How do I automatically extract just the IP address?Because the method I just used would display `192.168.0.` instead

**EDIT**
I am using Java on Android Studio

**EDIT 2**
I used

`str = url.toString();
ip = str.substring(str.indexOf('/')+1, str.lastIndexOf(':');`

because the second one made me crash and I could not find ways to fix it

Comment: The method in the updated answer is better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit! :**
For Android (Java) use the following code :

```
(new URL(urlToParse)).getHost();
```

or if you already have an URL object just the `getHost()` method (for hostname)

`getAuthority()` - (for hostname:port)

for other parts consult https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

---

What language are you using ?

How about using String.split(':') or String.lastIndexOf(':') (and indexof '/') if they are available in your language of choice ?

You can also use `regex` - Regular Expressions but that might be an overkill for such a simple task. But it sure is more accurate/correct.

Also many languages provide URL parsing for you to extract the hostname/ip-address .

naive method :

```
str = url.toString();
ip = str.substring(str.indexOf('/')+1, str.lastIndexOf(':');
```

less naive method :

```
str = url.toString();
ip = str.split('/')[2].split(':')[0];
```

regex (only for ip-address based urls) :

```
/$https?:\/\/([0-9\.]*?)(:[0-9]*?)?/
```

Comment: ,I am using Java on Android Studio,I will test the answer you gave me and hope it works.Thanks!

Comment: Thank You!It works and this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score -1):

```
    String s = "http://192.168.0.123:321";
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("://"), s.indexOf(":"));

    Output: 192.168.0.123
```

Comment: The accepted answer for this post is a lot safer than what you are suggesting.